# I need help solving solving an integral that describes the acceleration of a car travelling on a circular hill.

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

So there is a 1500 kg car travelling at 60km/h over a circular hill that has a vertical radius of 200 m. So the coefficient of static friction is 0.7 and the car starts applying the brakes when its 50 m out from the crest of the circular hill and the car is supposed to stop exactly on the crest. With this information I need to find the minimum stopping distance, which I believe I can get from finding the deceleration of the car and then plugging it into a kinematics equation.

Using some known physics equations I managed to find an equation that describes the acceleration of the car. It is:

$$a = 6.86 \cos \frac{(at^3)}{200} - 0.0035a^2t^2$$

Now I need to find the average acceleration between 0 and 2.43 s, for which I need to integrate the integral as such:

$$\int_{0}^{2.43} \left( 6.86 \cos \frac{(at^3)}{200} - 0.0035a^2t^2\right)\mathrm dt$$

So I'm just wondering is this even possible to do? Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your equation for the acceleration you have $a$ on both sides? Why is that?

Comment: What's a "circular hill"? Hills are three-dimensional, circles are two-dimensional. What's a "vertical radius"? The radius of a circle is the same whether it's vertical or horizontal or somewhere in between.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the equation for $a$ you are using?

Comment: "$50$ m out" along the surface of the hill, horizontal distance only, or something else? Minimum stopping distance measured how and under what circumstances? Assuming the brakes are fully applied at "$50$ m out", the conditions of the problem would seem to imply that the minimum stopping distance is $50$ meters for the car at that point on the hill when measured in whatever way you measured "$50$ m out". But surely that's not the question.

Answer (score 1):

As @AntonVrdoljak commented, if your equation is correct, you cannot continue if you do not know at least an approximate function $a(t)$.

Rewriting your equation with whole numbers, we have
$$a+\frac{7 a^2 t^2}{2000}-\frac{343}{50} \cos \left(\frac{a
   t^3}{200}\right)=0$$

Suppose that the argument of the cosine is small and use Taylor expansion around $a=0$ followed by power series reversion. This should give you things such as
$$a=\frac{343}{50}-\frac{823543 t^2}{5000000}+\frac{1977326743
   t^4}{250000000000}-\frac{40353607
   t^6}{10000000000}+\cdots$$
and
$$ \cos \left(\frac{at^3}{200}\right)=1-\frac{117649 t^6}{200000000}+\frac{282475249
   t^8}{10000000000000}+\cdots$$

Now, you can compute the definite integral.